# MySQL Truncated Double Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am extracting the number of ip addresses that attempt to SSH in to a server per day and recording this into a second table. As these records will be taken during the day, and more attempts may be made during the day, I only go up to yesterdays date, as the full count of todays attempts will be available tomorrow.

When I run the code below I get a 'Error in query (1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:' warning.

```
INSERT INTO secondary_table (
 user_key,
 hostname,
 dateField,
 ipAddress,
 comment,
 hitCount)
SELECT primary_table.user_key,
 primary_table.hostname,
 primary_table.dateField,
 primary_table.ipAddress,
 'Failed SSH login',
 COUNT(primary_table.ipAddress) 
FROM primary_table

LEFT JOIN secondary_table
ON secondary_table.user_key = primary_table.user_key
AND secondary_table.hostname = primary_table.hostname
AND secondary_table.dateField = primary_table.dateField
AND secondary_table.ipAddress = primary_table.ipAddress
AND secondary_table.comment = primary_table.comment

WHERE primary_table.comment = 'Failed SSH login'
AND primary_table.dateField < (SELECT MAX(dateField) FROM primary_table WHERE ipAddress > 1)
AND secondary_table.hostname IS NULL

GROUP BY user_key, hostname, dateField, ipAddress, primary_table.comment;
```

The primary and secondary tables are:

```
-- primary_table
id  int(11) Auto Increment   
user_key    varchar(255) NULL
dateField   date NULL    
hostname    varchar(255) NULL    
ipAddress   varchar(255) NULL    
comment varchar(255) NULL

-- secondary_table
id  int(11) Auto Increment   
user_key    varchar(255) NULL    
hostname    varchar(255) NULL    
dateField   date NULL    
ipAddress   varchar(255) NULL    
comment varchar(255) NULL    
hitCount    int(11) NULL
```

When I run the SELECT query portion by itself, I get the results I would expect.

What I am looking for is to insert any entries which dont already exist into the secondary table, based on the user_key, hostname, date and ipaddress fields.

```
SELECT primary_table.user_key,
 primary_table.hostname,
 primary_table.dateField,
 primary_table.ipAddress,
 comment,
 COUNT(primary_table.ipAddress) 
FROM primary_table

WHERE primary_table.comment = 'Failed SSH login'
AND primary_table.dateField < (SELECT MAX(dateField) FROM primary_table WHERE ipAddress > 1)

GROUP BY user_key, hostname, dateField, ipAddress, primary_table.comment;
```

```
user_key       | hostname | logDate    | ipAddress   | comment          | COUNT(primary_table.ipAddress)
abcde1234567890| server01 | 23/02/2020 | 10.10.10.10 | Failed SSH login | 2480
abcde1234567890| server01 | 23/02/2020 | 10.10.10.11 | Failed SSH login | 2479
```

Comment: Can you check what is the value you are getting with count, just select without insert

Comment: @DeepakKumar COUNT() returns BIGINT, not DOUBLE.

Comment: Check does any INSERT trigger exists on secondary_table.

Comment: FROM primary_table WHERE ipAddress > 1 , ipAddress is varchar you cannot use > 1